Why Firefox flicker after setting GPU as default graphics renderer?
Machine: Dell Inspiron 15 5567
CPU: Intel i5-7200U
Op Sys: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
RAM: 16GB
GPUs:
(1) Integrated Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
(2) AMD Radeon R7 M445
============================================================
As per the usual advice when running a new version of Ubuntu on a machine with a Radeon graphics card, I set the environment variable DRI_PRIME=1 so as to make the Radeon GPU my primary renderer. I also made the following settings to Firefox's about:config
layers.acceleration.force-enabled               true

gfx.webrender.all                               true

Without doing this the system defaulted to using the integrated Intel graphics card.
The trouble is that after rebooting I have an intermittent flicker on Firefox and to a lesser degree on Thunderbird. The flicker often lapses to the screen multi-image below for a second or two (sometimes a few seconds):

Can anyone suggest a remedy for this unwanted flicker ?
EDIT

BIOS is 1.5.0 which is the most up to date according to Dell.

Disabling hardware acceleration and other in-browser performance settings makes no difference.

Obviously commenting out DRI_PRIME=1 in the .profile file will remove the flickering. But this is accepting defeat in deploying the Radeon GPU as primary renderer for display.

On reverting to Xorg from Wayland, the flicker seems to have been eliminated.



Referred to Firefox forums but no response to date.
